# StdDraw in Eclipse

Tags: java, stddraw

So i need to draw some small .gif pictures with the help of StdDraw (it MUST be StdDraw), but im running into an really stupid error. My Code is:

```
        while(true){

            StdDraw.setXscale(-R,R);
            StdDraw.setYscale(-R,R);

            StdDraw.picture(0, 0, "starfield.jpg");

        }
```

where R is a Double and starfield.jpg is the Background Picture.

The Error i get when trying to run this is:

```
Exception in thread "main" sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider it.tidalwave.imageio.arw.ARWImageReaderSpi not found
    at sun.misc.Service.fail(Service.java:129)
    at sun.misc.Service.access$000(Service.java:111)
    at sun.misc.Service$LazyIterator.next(Service.java:274)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry$1.run(IIORegistry.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerInstalledProviders(IIORegistry.java:232)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerStandardSpis(IIORegistry.java:167)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:120)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:142)
    at apple.awt.CToolkit.registerDefaultServices(CToolkit.java:1346)
    at apple.awt.CToolkit.<init>(CToolkit.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:859)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:826)
    at java.awt.Window.getToolkit(Window.java:1177)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:397)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:433)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:158)
    at StdDraw.init(StdDraw.java:173)
    at StdDraw.<clinit>(StdDraw.java:145)
    at Sonnensystem.main(Sonnensystem.java:58)
```

And because of this beeng a really huge error, i could not find any solution via Google, and i cant find the error myself. So if anyone can point me in the righ direction, this would be great!

I added the stdlib.jar as External Archive as described in this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taJovOCBPS4

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the solution, I needed to export my code as Runnable JAR, after that it worked as expected.